# How to use funcAnimation while using Multiprocessing in python 3

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, streaming

hope you're all doing great.
I am quite new in Python and am working on a tiny client- server project, where I am receiving data from the client and the goal is that the server plot this data in graphic form in real time.
This is the code from the server part, which I am having struggles right now.

```py
    import socket
    import sys
    import math
    import numpy as np
    import struct
    import time
    import os
    import ctypes as c
    import multiprocessing
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import animation
    from matplotlib import style
    
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 6543
    receive_size = 4096
    
    
    
    def run_server(shared_data_time, shared_data_signal):   
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server:  
            server.bind((HOST, PORT))
            server.listen()
            conn, addr = server.accept() 
            with conn:
                print(f"Connected by {addr}")
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(receive_size)
                    if len(data) == 4096:                     
                        payload  = np.frombuffer(data, dtype = 'float64')
                        print(payload)
                        print('received data')
                        deinterleaved = [payload[idx::2] for idx in range(2)] 
                        shared_data_time = deinterleaved[0]   
                        shared_data_signal = deinterleaved[1]
                        print(f'received {len(data)} bytes')  
                        
    
    
    
    
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        HOST = '127.0.0.1'
        PORT = 6543
        receive_size = 4096
        
       
        shared_data_time = multiprocessing.Array('f', 2048)
        shared_data_signal = multiprocessing.Array('f', 2048)
        process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = run_server, args =(shared_data_time, shared_data_signal))
        process1.start()
        
    
        def animate(i, shared_data_time, shared_data_signal):
            ax1.clear()
            ax1.plot(shared_data_time, shared_data_signal)
    
       
        style.use('fivethirtyeight')
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs = (shared_data_time, shared_data_signal), interval = 100) 
        plt.show()
```

The communication between server and client works but I am only getting am empty graph, with no actualization. Could everyone helpe me? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're just over-writing the shared array in your child process rather than updating the values. Try `shared_data_time[:] = deinterleaved[0]` instead to copy values into the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without having access to the server you connect to, it's difficult to determine the exact problem, but please see this example I made to animate data coming from a child process via shared `multiprocessing.Array`'s:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
from time import sleep, time


def server(arr_x, arr_y):
    #tie shared buffers to numpy arrays
    x = np.frombuffer(arr_x.get_obj(), dtype='f4')
    y = np.frombuffer(arr_y.get_obj(), dtype='f4')
    T = time()
    while True:
        t = time() - T #elapsed time
        #we should technically lock access while we're writing to the array,
        #  but mistakes in the data are not real important if it's just a gui.
        x[:] = np.linspace(t, t + np.pi*2, len(x)) #update data in shared array
        y[:] = np.sin(x)
        sleep(1/30) #data updating faster or slower than animation framerate is not a big issue...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot()
    
    #init data
    arr_x = mp.Array('f', 1000) #type "d" == np.dtype("f8") 
    arr_y = mp.Array('f', 1000)
    
    #tie shared buffers to numpy arrays
    x = np.frombuffer(arr_x.get_obj(), dtype='f4')
    y = np.frombuffer(arr_y.get_obj(), dtype='f4')
    
    #calculate initial value
    x[:] = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, len(x))
    y[:] = np.sin(x)
    
    #daemon process to update values (server)
    mp.Process(target=server, args=(arr_x, arr_y), daemon=True).start()
    
    #plot initial data because we need a line instance to update continually
    line = ax.plot(x, y)[0]
    #fps counting vars
    last_second = time()
    last_frame = 0
    
    def animate(frame, x, y):
        global last_second, last_frame
        #might be cleaner to wrap animate and use nonlocal rather than global, 
        #  but it would be more complicated for just this simple example.
        
        #set data with most recent values
        line.set_data(x, y)
        line.axes.set_xlim(x[0], x[999])
        
        #periodically report fps
        interval = time() - last_second
        if  interval >= 1:
            print("fps: ", (frame-last_frame) / interval)
            last_second = time()
            last_frame = frame
    
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(x, y), interval = 20)
    plt.show()
```

FPS counting can obviously be removed easily, and converting shared arrays to numpy arrays isn't strictly necessary, but I find it easier to work with, and it is not difficult.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! It is working now